# in method 'new_panel' expected argument 1 of type wxWindow*

Tags: python, user-interface, window, wxpython, wxglade

I have a class `A (wx.Panel)` which I believe is its parent class and this panel has been created using automatically generated wxGlade code and it has the init as

```
wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
```

now Class B inherits class A. Class B(class A) and the init for class B is

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    A.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
```

When I try to create an object of class B, how should i instantiate it?

`obj = B()`. I know I cannot have a None because a parent is definitely needed. Why do I land in the error "in method 'new_panel' expected argument 1 of type wxWindow*"

-B

Answer (score 1):

just like you would instantiate a wxPanel

```
f=wx.Frame(None,-1,"Some Frame")
b = B(f,-1) 
f.Show()
```

Comment: I am still not very sure if I get that. I changed a few things around.I have a "class A(wx.ScrolledWindow)" and "class B" is the child inherited from "Class A". "Class B" has init -> "def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):" and " A.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)". If I want to instantiate "Class B" inside a global function, like obj = class B() -- what parameters would i pass to it?

Comment: you just need to pass it a parent window as the first argument ... in my example the frame is the parent window (`-1` just means auto-assign the window ID which is what you almost always want to do) ... a panel must be attached to another panel or a frame (or some other wxWidget)

Comment: Do you mean obj = wx.ScrolledWindow(-1)?. I thought the parent class name was needed for instantiation ..Also this is a global function inside which I am instantiating. Could you please explain it to me exactly what it would look like based on my first comment for your answer?

Comment: no ... parent is a parent window ... not a parent class ... just run my example solution... the frame,f is the parent window, that B is attached to ... but B inherits its class from its class parent(wx.ScrolledPanel) ... they are different types of parents

Comment: I really dont follow- How would I instantiate class B?